# Automatic open table on phpMyAdmin-login

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin

I want phpMyAdmin to automatically open a table, when I log in to it.
Is there a way to do this?

My reason:
In 90% of the cases I'm working in the same table in phpMyAdmin. 
So the two clicks in the nav each time I start phpMyAdmin are often useless.
But I of course want the possibility to change to other tables.

Comment: This is not a programming related issue. Also the fact you are using mostly one table makes me wondering if there couldnt be a better solution like splitting the data into multiple tables? You could, tho, bookmark the url leading to your database->table, which would imitate what you want without you having to change configs (if there is for that) or hack into the core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bookmark the url to view this specific table. You will be redirected to login, and back to that specific view afterwards